# Excel RTD multiple cells

Tags: c#, excel, real-time, rtd

I did a single cell subscription, so when I put the formula into the cell, it updates it correctly.

Now, I'm returning an object with multiple values and I want to display all of them in Excel cells. Is it possibly to only put a formula in 1A, subscribe once, get all values at once, and then distribute the information from one object to 1A, 1B, 1C... Or is the only way to subscribe individually to each field and put an RTD formula for every cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a workaround using a VBA function. Create your Excel sheet, make column headings that will match the fields that you need, put a formula in your 1A cell, and run the VBA function.

The function is just a for loop over all columns in Range (number of rows is still up to), that just gets the column header value and does your magic and the rest is up to simple string manipulation of getting the formula, converting it to string and replacing `$C1` to `$D1` etc.

Example:

```
"=RTD("ProgId", , "Your arbitrary parameter here", $C1)"
```

Wouldn't say it is the fastest way, but it is a good solution